# Acquiring British citizenship

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, passport, relocation, uk-citizenship

I was born in South Africa in 2007 and my mom was born in the UK before 1986.

My mom and dad were never married and my mother has full custody of me.

My dad was born in South Africa as well. Do I have British citizenship through my mother?

Comment: Was your mom born in the UK before **1983**? Or does your mom otherwise have British citizenship?